# How can I implement multiple payment plans with different currencies in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I have a website built with HTML, CSS, Javascript & PHP without using any framework. I have also rebuilt the whole site using wordpress. But the only concern remains is that, in the previous site, there was paying subscribers who subscribed with their country's currency and a standard plan (2.5 USD, 2 GBP, 2 Euro). But in wordpress, there is no plugin to handle multiple plans with multiple currencies. What is the feasible solution to this problem? Is it possible to do Custom payment gateway development within wordpress?

Tried all the plugins, but none of them support multiple currencies with plans with paypal

Comment: WordPress is a PHP based CMS. Any existing code you have from the old website can be ported over to the new one, you may need to make adjustments though. Same thing applies to the data you have on the old database.